# C - Segmentation fault with ptrace and waitpid

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

For a labs school in C, we have to code a process (we are going to call it A) who need to attach to another process (B) and put a trap in a function (trap instruction is 0xCC) so we did it but when B enter is this function we have a Segmentation Fault

So this is the process A which attach to the other processes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

pid_t pidTargetProgram;
FILE *file;
int buf;
char path[50];
long long int address;


if (argc == 2) {
   fprintf(stderr, "Argument waited !\n");
   exit(1);
 }

// The second argument is the PID of the program 
pidTargetProgram = atoi(argv[1]);

// The third argument is the address of the function where we are going to put a trap
address = strtoll(argv[2], NULL, 16);

// We put the path to the file mem of the program 
sprintf(path, "/proc/%s/mem", argv[1]);

// We attach to the other program
if(ptrace(PTRACE_ATTACH, pidTargetProgram, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
  perror("Error with ptrace_attach !");
  exit(1);
}

// We wait it to be synchronize
if (waitpid(pidTargetProgram, NULL, WUNTRACED) < 0) {
  perror("Error with waitpid !\n");
  exit(0);
  }



// We open the file mem in read and write mode
  if ((file = fopen(path, "r+")) == NULL) {
    perror("Error during the opening of mem file from process !");
    exit(1);
  }



// We place our cursor on the address of the function
  fseek(file, address, SEEK_SET);

  char trap[] = {0xCC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

  // We put the trap in the foo function
  if (fwrite(trap, 1, 5, file) < 1) {
    perror("Error to write !");
    exit(1);
    }

  int counter = 0;

  fseek(file, address, SEEK_SET);

  // We print the other function's memory
  while (fread(&buf, 4, 1, file) > 0) {
    printf("Line n°%d : 0x%x\n", counter++, buf);
    }

  // We close the file
  if (fclose(file) != 0) {
    perror("Error during the closing !");
    exit(1);
  }

  // We said to continue to the other program
  if (ptrace(PTRACE_CONT, pidTargetProgram, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
    perror("Error during ptrace_cont !\n");
    exit(1);
    }

  printf("continued !\n");

  // We wait the other program stop
  if (waitpid(pidTargetProgram, NULL, WUNTRACED) < 0) {
    perror("Error with waitpid !\n");
    exit(0);
    }

  printf("Trace declenched !\n");

  // We detach 
  if (ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pidTargetProgram, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
    perror("Error during ptrace_detach !");
    exit(1);
    }

  printf("detach success ! \n");

  return 0;
}
```

And this is the processus B :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

// Function to execute to take the trap
void foo(){
  int i = 0;
  printf("foo :::: %d", i);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  char text[10];
  pid_t pidProgram;

  // We get the PID
  pidProgram = getpid();

  // We print the PID
  fprintf(stdout, "PID's program : %d\n", pidProgram);

  // We print the address of foo()
  fprintf(stdout, "foo address : %p\n", &(foo));

  // We stop the program to lunch the other program
  fgets(text, 10, stdin);

  int i;
  for(i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++){
    foo(i);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

To execute this, we start first the B so it gives us the PID and the address and it makes a pause at the fgets.
So after that, we start the program A and we give it the PID and the address, it's stop at the second waitpid.
After that we continue B and write something and we have a segmentation fault and stop. We don't understand why because in the memory we can clearly see the trap (0xCC) and it doesn't work
But on the program A, we have 
Trace declenched !
detach success !

So no error on A but B have segmentation fault

Do you have any idea for this ?
We use Centos as Operating System.
Sorry for my english.

Thank

Julien

Answer (score 5):

The program is working as expected:

First, you change the running process image to set `0xcc` at the start of function `foo`, which triggers a breakpoint/trap.

Then, you call this function while the process is traced by process `a`.
So this call

```
waitpid(pidTargetProgram, NULL, WUNTRACED) < 0) // Process a
```

returns. Now you detach from process b with

```
ptrace(PTRACE_DETACH, pidTargetProgram, NULL, NULL);
```

however, you did not restore the overwritten instructions in the process previously! So, the next instructions are corrupted and lead to the segfault you observe. Furthermore, the process restarts at the next instruction PC+1 (directly after the 0xcc), so you need to set the PC back one byte using `PTRACE_GETREGS/PTRACE_SETREGS`

Btw. it is more elegant to use the ptrace interface to set and reset the breakpoint instruction with `PTRACE_POKETEXT` instead of using the `/proc/pid/mem` way.

TL;DR: You need to restore the original instructions first and reset the PC before restarting process b, then it should work as you expect.

Comment: But I don't understand when I need to restore the overwritten instructions because when the program B stop at fgets, my program A starts and stops at the second waitpid. If a put a ptrace(PTRACE_POKETEXT, pid, address, theOldInstruction) after the waitpid, it will never be seen by B and if I put ptrace before the waitpid I will overwritten at the trap and B will never execute the trap.

Comment: @JulienRC You have to restart execution of your process B at the trap instruction to guarantee a consistent execution of the process. And it is a loop, correct? So it will be executed 100 times